# site can't be reached error while accessing jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I installed jenkins on ubuntu it is successfully installed. But while i access through browser by using IP_Address:8080 it shows site can't be reached shows.
i tried sudo ufw allow 8080 and sudo ufw enable but it can't work

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-61:~$ sudo ufw status

Status: active


To                         Action      From

--                         ------      ----

8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere

OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere

8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


 
sudo ufw enable
o/p -Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? Y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup


ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-61:~$ ss -tnl|grep :8080

LISTEN 0      50                 *:8080            *:*
```

Comment: Please edit the actual and complete error messages into your question. Also show the output of `ss -tnl |grep :8080` from the server.

Comment: i tried this command and get output as follows
ubuntu@ip-172-31-32-61:~$ ss -tnl|grep :8080
LISTEN 0      50                 *:8080            *:*